# How to install sbt-idea and use gen-idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

I have downloaded and installed sbt and plugin for gen-idea.
But the built projects can not be run on idea.
Also the "project" folder is not generated when I run gen-idea.
Can someone please tell me how I should install sbt and sbt-idea plugin and configure it, as I think the problem here is configuring.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about proper installation and configuration of the plugin. A better answer would be found within the plugin documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all sbt projects you have a `project` folder (in the root of your project directory). You need to create there a file called - `plugins.sbt` and place there:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

Notice that i have a blank line between. Then, if you have an opened sbt session call `reload` command, you can call `gen-idea` to generate idea files, also i recomend to add `sbt-classifiers` to download sources.

Otherwise you can make this plugin visible globally to all your sbt project, by placing the same two line in the `~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` file.

When you have generated this project, in IDEA choose `Open Project` and choose your newly generated project. This should work, if not, provide some additional info.

Comment: thanks. I did same. but after opening it in idea I tried to run it. It says 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrong arguments: [scala.tools.nsc.CompileClient] at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ClassRunner.main(ClassRunner.java:30)

Comment: When you do this in IDEA, for example with sbt plugin, then IDEA should pop-up with a `reload project` window.

Comment: Is `gen-idea` still needed when we are using idea sbt and Scala plugins?

Comment: It has to be `1.6.0` only now. `1.6.0-SNAPSHOT` is a 404